# TrustSSLcertificate usage in Selenium RC/webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

While executing selenium RC scripts for every execution it is asking me to trust the website which is SSL certificate error , please help me with step by step process on how to avoid this while executing selenium rc scripts without manually clicking on the Get certificate button.

Browser: Mozilla
OS: Windows 7
IDE: Eclipse.

Comment: Have you checked the official selenium documentation site -- seleniumhq.org

Answer (score 0):

When you run the selenium server run it with -trustAllSSLCertificates extension

Ex : `java -jar selenium-server-standalone -trustAllSSLCertifictes -userExtensions userExtensions.js`

Answer (score 0):

Find the selenium standalone server.jar, unzip it and dump all the contents into a folder. Go into the folder, and go into sslSupport, there should be a security certificate called cybervillainsCA. You can add this certificate to your browser.